# Where Is The History Of The Azure Classic Pipelines Kept?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I prefer the classic editor in Azure pipelines as I can see in a glance of about a second or two what is happening.

I see the benefit of versioning the pipeline, I just don't want to have to learn another DSL/schema if I don't have to.

The classic view has a history of changes and the content of the JSON it creates is very clear.

Where is this stored and is it possible to direct this to the same repo I would have used for the yaml pipelines?

Comment: it's in Azure DevOps SQL, not in a git repo.